# how to create method takes task lambda expression async

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> getOne(HttpRequestMessage request, int id)
{ 

   return CreateResponse(async () =>
    {
        var category = await _unitOfWork.Categories.GetSingleAsync(id);
        var categoryVm = Mapper.Map<Category, CategoryViewModel>(category);

        HttpResponseMessage response = request.CreateResponse<CategoryViewModel>(HttpStatusCode.OK, categoryVm);

        return response;
    });
}
```

Base Class

```
protected Task<IHttpActionResult> CreateResponse(Func<IHttpActionResult, Task> function)
{
    IHttpActionResult response = null;
    try
    {
        response = function.Invoke();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Read up on **Cross cutting concerns**.

You are giving yourself unnecessary trouble. Your example can be reduced to :

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> getOne(int id) {
    var category = await _unitOfWork.Categories.GetSingleAsync(id);
    var categoryVm = Mapper.Map<Category, CategoryViewModel>(category);
    return Ok(categoryVm);
}
```

Try to keep controller lean.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38032237/5233410) answer