# Global Exception Handler for all types of the Exceptions in WebApi2

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-web-api2

I'm working on Exception Handling on WebApi and i need to send error messages to my Clients through adding `HttpStatusCode` and `ErrorBody`.

i have tried and i have found some useful solutions, Like `ExceptionFilters`, `HttpResponseMessage` and some Global exception handlers but i didn't deep in them because i am in feasibility study.

some of them, Like `ExceptionFilters` runs before/after getting the Exceptions and they were useful for Logging purpose. but all of them just throw my running code into a runtime exception.

I spent a day to find, how can i collect and get rid of VisualStudio runtime errors, when i run an `throw new ...` expression; but i couldn't reach to what i was searching for.

When i choose `HttpResponseMessage` as return types of my ActionMethods, it's pretty easy way to make an error and send it back to the client request. 
but when i want to choose another way, for example :

```
 public User GetAllUsers()
 {
     ... //Some Codes
     {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
     }
     else { ... }
 }
```

it just drive me to a runtime error (i think, it's just a warning because i only need to press F5 to get rid of this server side Bump :) )  and after all i will see my generated error message on Client-Side application.

I don't want to use `HttpResponseMessage` as output type of my `ActionMethods`, because I'm responsible to develop both Front-End and Back-End and it takes a wearisome check to see "What is the type of this ActionMethod ?"

how can i do this work ?

Comment: See if this provides some help https://stackoverflow.com/a/38032237/5233410