# Handle all exceptions globally in ASP.Net Web Api (global.asax)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, exception

I'm currently using `Application_Error` in `global.asax` to handle Web API exceptions, pass them to an error logger and log them.

```
    void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Server.GetLastError() != null)
        {
            exceptionController.Log(Server.GetLastError());
            Server.ClearError();
        }
    }
```

It catches some exceptions, but not all - such as 404 errors from a server, etc. How can I catch more exceptions myself (which I assume will mean overriding ASP.Net's default exception handling). Is there a way to do this all from `global.asax`, or is there more to it? I'd like to avoid `try catch finally` blocks on all of my controllers.

Mods - there are a million threads about this, but there's also a million equally unique answers from many different time periods. I'm so confused that I felt compelled to ask once again in 2018.

Comment: Take a look at an answer I gave here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38025305/best-practice-for-error-handling-with-asp-net-web-api/38032237#38032237

Comment: Some of your errors do not come from application like address not found. That you have to handle at client side, if you have control over it. For most of the issues check for HttpWebResponse at the end

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks for that answer. But the 'Global Error Handling in ASP.NET Web API 2` article that you linked is - I believe - out of date. And the way you posted is lean, but still requires that I add attributes on all of my controllers. Is there a way in 2018 to not even have to add any logic to my controllers - just have a global exception class that overrides default exception handling and delivers exception messages, sends emails, etc for any type of exception? I'm really struggling with this - there's so many ways to go about it and Microsoft doesn't seem to document it too well IMO

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle what would otherwise be a 404 from the framework you can add a route to handle "everything else" and return a customized response.

We have a catch-all route at the end of our route tables that looks a bit like

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "NotImplemented",
            routeTemplate: "{*data}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "notimplemented", data = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

where we generate a custom response.  You might be able to do something similar in your route table.