# Proper way to handle exceptions in an API Controller in MVC

Tags: api, model-view-controller

What is the "proper" way of handling errors in a MVC application for a API Controller?

I have this implemented: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/exception-handling-in-asp-net-web-api/

But on our main controllers I can just inherit from a : BaseController as the below:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Base Controller
    /// </summary>
    /// <seealso cref="Controller" />
    public abstract partial class BaseController : Controller
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Called when an unhandled exception occurs in any action. Will log to the database.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filterContext">Information about the current request and action.</param>
        protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {


            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
                filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
                {
                    Data = new { success = false, errorMessage = "An error has occurred and has been logged. Please contact an administrator if the issue persists." },
                    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                };

                base.OnException(filterContext);
            }
        }
    }
```

I do not like how I have to add an attribute to the top of the class of each API Controller though.

Is there a better way or the way I have it implemented is OK?

Comment: Depending on the version you are using this might be of some help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38025305/best-practice-for-error-handling-with-asp-net-web-api/38032237#38032237

Comment: @Nkosi: Thank you. I'll post the answer. I found I could register it in my WebApiConfig file. I had this, but I thought I had to do it on each controller as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Registers the specified configuration.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="config">The configuration.</param>
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

            config.Filters.Add(new APICustomExceptionFilter());
        }
    }
```

I was able to register it ONCE in my Register method of  my WebAPIConfig.

This will do the trick so I do not have to decorate it on each API Controller in my application.